# Delete duplicates with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with deleting duplicate data.

These are my two tables.

**1. VL_Wohneinheiten**

```
TABLE [dbo].[VL_Wohneinheiten](
[VLW_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[VLW_Liegenschaft] [int] NOT NULL,
[VLW_FlatID] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
[VLW_OTOID] [nvarchar](25) NOT                                           
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,                                    
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
[VLW_ID] ASC)                                                            
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,           
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)         
ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]                                                        
GO
```

**2. VL_Liegenschaften**

```
TABLE [dbo].[VL_Liegenschaften](
[VLI_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[VLI_Strasse] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[VLI_Nummer] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[VLI_PLZ] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
[VLI_Ort] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
[VLI_Import_flag] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[VLI_OMDF_ID] [varchar](20) NULL, PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [VLI_ID] ASC)  
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,           
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)          
ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]  GO
```

The connection between these two tables is done via VL_Wohneinheiten.VLV_Liegenschaft = VL_Liegenschaften.VLI_ID

I want to delete now all data duplicated by OTO_ID, and which in the table VL_Liegenschaften VLI_OMDF_ID are NULL

in an image example to want to make a query, is it possible to do it?

[image]

I have set the picture as an additional explanation, but I just want to explain more precisely what I want to do.

This is my one query with which I tried to select this information, I'm not sure if it's a real query in case it is how can I delete those displayed on the basis of it?

```
  select  t1.VLW_OTOID,  t2.VLI_OMDF_ID from VL_Wohneinheiten as t1     
  INNER JOIN VL_Liegenschaften as t2 ON t1.VLW_Liegenschaft = t2.VLI_ID 
  GROUP BY  t1.VLW_OTOID, t2.VLI_OMDF_ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1              
  and t2.VLI_OMDF_ID IS NULL
```

Thank you very much for your help.

```
INSERT [dbo].[VL_Wohneinheiten] ([VLW_ID], [VLW_Liegenschaft], [VLW_FlatID], [VLW_OTOID], [VLW_Koax], [VLW_Ready], [VLW_Fiber], [VLW_Status], [VLW_Status_text], [VLW_Import_flag], [VLW_Owner], [VLW_Caretaker], [VLW_Building_Type_id], [VLW_Building_Type], [ID]) VALUES (25822, 79045, N'', N'B.111.253.375.3', 0, N'                         ', 1, 0, N'Assigned', 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 107184) INSERT [dbo].[VL_Wohneinheiten] ([VLW_ID], [VLW_Liegenschaft], [VLW_FlatID], [VLW_OTOID], [VLW_Koax], [VLW_Ready], [VLW_Fiber], [VLW_Status], [VLW_Status_text], [VLW_Import_flag], [VLW_Owner], [VLW_Caretaker], [VLW_Building_Type_id], [VLW_Building_Type], [ID]) VALUES (25823, 79046, N'', N'B.111.253.375.3', 0, N'                         ', 1, 0, N'Assigned', 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 107185) INSERT [dbo].[VL_Wohneinheiten] ([VLW_ID], [VLW_Liegenschaft], [VLW_FlatID], [VLW_OTOID], [VLW_Koax], [VLW_Ready], [VLW_Fiber], [VLW_Status], [VLW_Status_text], [VLW_Import_flag], [VLW_Owner], [VLW_Caretaker], [VLW_Building_Type_id], [VLW_Building_Type], [ID]) VALUES (21638, 74861, N'', N'B.111.253.375.3', 0, N'                         ', 1, 0, N'Assigned', 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 103000)INSERT [dbo].[VL_Wohneinheiten] ([VLW_ID], [VLW_Liegenschaft], [VLW_FlatID], [VLW_OTOID], [VLW_Koax], [VLW_Ready], [VLW_Fiber], [VLW_Status], [VLW_Status_text], [VLW_Import_flag], [VLW_Owner], [VLW_Caretaker], [VLW_Building_Type_id], [VLW_Building_Type], [ID]) VALUES (21639, 74862, N'', N'B.111.253.375.3', 0, N'                         ', 1, 0, N'Assigned', 1, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 103001)
```

```html
INSERT [dbo].[VL_Liegenschaften] ([VLI_ID], [VLI_Strasse], [VLI_Nummer], [VLI_PLZ], [VLI_Ort], [VLI_Import_flag], [VLI_OMDF_ID]) VALUES (74861, N'Zürcherstrasse', N'210', N'8500', N'Frauenfeld2', 0, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[VL_Liegenschaften] ([VLI_ID], [VLI_Strasse], [VLI_Nummer], [VLI_PLZ], [VLI_Ort], [VLI_Import_flag], [VLI_OMDF_ID]) VALUES (74862, N'Zürcherstrasse', N'210', N'8500', N'Frauenfeld2', 0, NULL)
INSERT [dbo].[VL_Liegenschaften] ([VLI_ID], [VLI_Strasse], [VLI_Nummer], [VLI_PLZ], [VLI_Ort], [VLI_Import_flag], [VLI_OMDF_ID]) VALUES (79045, N'Zürcherstrasse', N'210A', N'8500', N'Frauenfeld2', 0, N'FRA_12')
INSERT [dbo].[VL_Liegenschaften] ([VLI_ID], [VLI_Strasse], [VLI_Nummer], [VLI_PLZ], [VLI_Ort], [VLI_Import_flag], [VLI_OMDF_ID]) VALUES (79046, N'Zürcherstrasse', N'210A', N'8500', N'Frauenfeld2', 0, N'FRA_12')
```

Comment: This looks like MS SQL Server (not MySQL)

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya you are right!

Comment: What's the logical Primary Key for those tables (apparently it's not the `id`, otherwise you wouldn't have those duplicates you're trying to delete). And after the delete you will get invalid data in `VLW_Liegenschaft`, how to deal with it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the report, the link is via VLW_Liegenschaft-VLI_ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use row_number()

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=32f7806d19bbc5d77f369b1f200824e2

```
 select * from 
(select  t1.VLW_OTOID,  t2.VLI_OMDF_ID,row_number() over(partition by VLI_ID order by 
vli_id desc) as rn from VL_Wohneinheiten as t1     
INNER JOIN VL_Liegenschaften as t2 ON t1.VLW_Liegenschaft = t2.VLI_ID 
and t2.VLI_OMDF_ID IS NULL) a where rn=1
```

For deleting duplicate rows:

```
delete w from [dbo].[VL_Liegenschaften] w
inner join 
(select  *,row_number() over(partition by VLW_OTOID order by 
VLW_Liegenschaft desc) as rn from VL_Wohneinheiten as t1     
INNER JOIN VL_Liegenschaften as t2 ON t1.VLW_Liegenschaft = t2.VLI_ID 
) a on a.[VLI_ID]=w.[VLI_ID] where rn<>1
```

Comment: What I'm doing is showing me the error in the part (rownum () over (partition by VLI_ID order by)

Comment: r u using sql sever or mysql?

Comment: @ fa06 sql server

Comment: modified the query, you can check now, there is a typo error

Comment: Thanks for your help, the cookie works, and does this sort the toss like this just as I mentioned above in the picture or just take the first one out of duplicates?

Comment: I think this is how I can make a delete command from this select query

Comment: yes, for delete you need to apply some trick like rn<>1, so that will keep the most updated one and delete all other duplicate values

Comment: Can you please make me delete query?

Comment: can you provide some sample data with your table structure, as I need to test before providing you full query - just give some sample data with your question according to table structure

Comment: I put the data in question, look

Comment: Ok, let me check and let u know

Comment: @Michael, I've updated the answer also provide demo - you can check  there

Comment: That's what I mean :), thanks a lot for help, you really helped me a lot

Comment: glad to help u :)